# Selecting the desired rows group by in pandas dataframe based on column value change

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have source dataframe, df like below.

| order_id | prod_id | date | authorized |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | P | 2022-01-01 00:00:00 | N |
| 111 | P | 2022-01-02 00:00:00 | N |
| 111 | P | 2022-01-03 00:00:00 | Y |
| 111 | Q | 2022-01-02 00:00:00 | Y |
| 112 | P | 2022-01-01 00:00:00 | N |
| 112 | P | 2022-01-02 00:00:00 | Y |
| 112 | Q | 2022-01-01 00:00:00 | N |
| 112 | Q | 2022-01-02 00:00:00 | N |
| 112 | Q | 2022-01-03 00:00:00 | N |
| 112 | Q | 2022-01-04 00:00:00 | N |
| 113 | P | 2022-01-01 00:00:00 | N |
| 113 | P | 2022-01-02 00:00:00 | Y |
| 113 | P | 2022-01-03 00:00:00 | Y |
| 113 | P | 2022-01-04 00:00:00 | Y |
| 113 | P | 2022-01-05 00:00:00 | Y |
| 114 | Z | 2022-01-05 00:00:00 | Y |

my goal is to create a target dataframe like below

[image]

Here is the logic to be implemented for target dataframe creation:

a) for an order_id and prod_id combination take the first row(sorted by date ascending) where authorized=Y

b) for an order id and prod id combination, if none of the records have authorized = 'Y', take the first row,sorted by date ascending.

Is there any way to implement this efficiently, in Pandas?. I did some googling, but couldn't find a solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Good answers require good questions, please help make your problem understandable to all by improving your question. In general, the existing code and the expected result should be presented as text. thank you. (Provide your dataframe for example from output of `df.head().to_dict()`)

Comment: Please replace your first image by the output of `print(df.head(10).tostring())`

Comment: Thanks a lot @Corralient. Will check and update. I was trying to do the formatting u suggested. However pasting the output of print(df.head(10).tostring()) is messing the formatting. Dont know yet, how to paste a table in the question :(

Comment: I just discovered `print(df.to_markdown(index=False))` (need `tabulate` package)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort your dataframe by `authorized` and `date` columns then group by `order_id` and `product_id` columns. Finally, get the first row of each group.

```
# Convert date as datetime64
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], dayfirst=False)

out = df.sort_values(['authorized', 'date'], ascending=[False, True]) \
        .groupby(['order_id', 'prod_id']).first().reset_index()
print(out)

# Output
   order_id prod_id       date authorized
0       111       P 2022-01-03          Y
1       111       Q 2022-01-02          Y
2       112       P 2022-01-02          Y
3       112       Q 2022-01-01          N
4       113       P 2022-01-02          Y
5       114       Z 2022-01-05          Y
```

Comment: @jorge. '1/2/2022' is 2nd january or 1st february?

Comment: How do we select the first instance of authorized='Y'. I believe simple sorting wont work here

Comment: it is 1st Januaray. All days in are in Jan 2022 in the sample dataframe

Comment: I updated my answer. I just swapped `authorized` and `date` columns to sort. Can you check your output for `(112, Q)`

Comment: Sorry, it was a mistake. I updated the output. Thanks Corralien for pointing it.

Comment: So my output is right, isn't it? Now, I believe simple sorting work here :)

Comment: Thanks for pasting the table in the question. By the way, how did u do it? Sorry, I am bit naive on stackoverflow formatting.

Comment: `pip install tabulate` and `print(df.to_markdown(index=False))`. After that you copy/paste the output to the post editor. That's all.